# Is it possible to run a node with only build file and boot node of the chain?

Tags: substrate-node-template, validator, nodes, bootnode

If i have build file(i.e target file) and boot node of the substrate chain.

Can I join the network by running my validator node?

Note: Our goal is to minimise the effort required for users who wish to operate a validator. or we have any other options to reduce the effort?